# Can I set a RouterLink for an entire table's row?

Tags: vuejs3, vuex, vue-router

Right now I have a method that, whenever a row is clicked, the clicked record's information is opened in a little window by pushing to the record route. This is kind of ok, but I would like the row to act exactly as a link, where you can ctrl+click to open it in a different tab or do the same thing by clicking it with the mouse wheel.

I was thinking about making the whole row a "RouterLink", but it looks like there's no way to do so. I could do every td of the table's trs a RouterLink, but I don't think this is the best way to do it.

What would be the best way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

HTML table won't allow the wrapping of `<tr>` elements, but you can just use a click handler and [programmatic navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html) instead. To open in a new tab, you'll need to use [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

```html
<tr @click="navigate">
  <td>cell1</td>
  <td>cell2</td>
</tr>
```

Composition API:

```js
<script setup>
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

const router = useRouter()
function navigate() {
  let route = router.resolve({ path: '/routepath' })
  // open in new tab
  window.open(route.href)
}
</script>
```

Options API:

```js
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    navigate() {
      let route = this.$router.resolve({ path: '/routepath' })
      // open in new tab
      window.open(route.href)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```